# Retain QGIS window layout

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is it possible (in QGIS 3.16) to retain the layout of windows. So whenever I open the project it opens as below?

[image]

Critically the Attribute table in Form view with the Pan option on the RHS and a python script open and running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running 3.28 in the Project Properties, General Settings I see the checkbox *"Remember attribute tables windows and docks between sessions"* which seems to do what you want.  Not sure when then was added.
[image]

Comment: That's great. I have never seen this and it will be very helpful BUT, unfortunetly, we are stuck in 3.16. If this can only happen in 3.28 and newer, it's a good reason to request the current LTR to be installed. I checked the Project-->Properties and Settings-->Options but can't find a similar option as in your screen grab.

Comment: Bummer :(   I had a look at the changelogs, seems like it was added in 3.26.  Best log that request for a version upgrade!